How to include Latex listing in a command using minipage?
I created a \fooCmd to typeset some text in a large file.
This typesetting is using a minipage environment.
And sometimes within the minipage environment, I would like to include some LaTeX listing.
However, when I do so, the LaTeX commands seems to be interpreted, while the same listing outside of my \fooCmd is working perfectly.
From previous questions here or here, I understand that is not easy to parse a listing environment inside a command due to token scanning, etc.
But even trying the different solution proposed, I still get errors.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{fancyvrb}

    \usepackage{listings}
        \lstset{%
            language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
            fancyvrb,
        }
        \lstMakeShortInline|

        \providecommand{\fooCmd}[4]{
           {#1}

            \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
                \textit{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}\dotfill\,{#3}\par
                \begingroup
                \vspace{0.5em}#4\par
                \endgroup
            \end{minipage}
        }

\begin{document}

   This my document 

    \fooCmd{first argument}
    {Second}{Third}{
        If I put my listing here, it is CRASH: %\protect\Verb+\newcommand{toto}+ %|\newcommand{toto}|
    }

   If I put my listing here, it is ok: |\newcommand{toto}|

\end{document}

So how to include Latex listing in a command that uses minipage ?

Use a custom environment instead of a custom command

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz do you want to write an answer showing that approach?

@Skillmon done - thanks for the reminder!

You can avoid such problems by using a custom environment instead of a command:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
  fancyvrb,
}
\lstMakeShortInline|

\newenvironment{fooenv}[3]{
  {#1}
  
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \textit{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}\dotfill\,{#3}\par
  \begingroup
  \vspace{0.5em}
}{
  \par
  \endgroup
  \end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}

  This my document 
  
  \begin{fooenv}{first argument}{Second}{Third}
     If I put my listing here, it is CRASH: 
     \protect\Verb+\newcommand{toto}+ %|\newcommand{toto}|
  \end{fooenv}
  
  If I put my listing here, it is ok: |\newcommand{toto}|

\end{document}


The following uses a verbatim argument to grab your fourth argument and then uses \scantokens to allow the code to be interpreted. Please note that this way the macro \foocmd is not allowed to be used as part of another macros argument (just like you found out about your verbatim material):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  language=[LaTeX]{TeX},
  fancyvrb,
}
\lstMakeShortInline|

\NewDocumentCommand \foocmd { m m m +v }
  {%
    {#1}\par
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
      \textit{\textbf{\textcolor{red}{#2}}}\dotfill\,{#3}\par
      \begingroup
      \vspace{0.5em}
      \begingroup
        \def\obeyedline{^^J}%
        \newlinechar=`^^J
        \expandafter
      \endgroup\scantokens\expanded{{#4\string\relax}}%
      \par
      \endgroup
    \end{minipage}
  }

\begin{document}

This my document 

\foocmd{first argument}
{Second}{Third}{
  If I put my listing here, it is CRASH: \protect\Verb+\newcommand{toto}+ %|\newcommand{toto}|
}

If I put my listing here, it is ok: |\newcommand{toto}|

\end{document}



It was not working with TeXLive 2023 but with 2024 it is working as expected.

@R.N yes, there was a change in the handling of +v in the LaTeX kernel, sorry.

No need to be sorry it was just a remark ;) However, I switch the validated answer to Sam's solution since it seems less sensible to other characters. For example, if I add brackets ( ) in the fourth argument with your solution it crashes, with Sam's answer it seems OK...

@R.N parentheses work just fine for me, you might ask a follow up question so that people (me) can take a look at it and debug (though not today, it's almost midnight where I live).

FYI: I was digging a bit more to prepare this following up question, and it seems that the issue was not from the parentheses but from a tab (typo) in my text. So sorry for the misleading information.
